# Double integral giving different answer

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So we had our quiz and everything. I just don’t get it why my answer is not correct like my teacher’s. Here it is:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_1^{e^x} \frac{x}{y} \,dy \,dx$$

So my first integral was: $\int_{-1}^1 (x\ln e-\ln1) \,dx$. So the final integral is just $x^2 /2$ if we plug the limits. It will be like this: $1^2 /2 - [(-1)^2 /2]$ and the answer is just zero.

Well according to my teacher the answer is $2/3$ and how can it be?

Another problem he gave was different and he also came up with different form. I just want to know where I went wrong if ever I messed the integral up.

$$\int_0^4 \int_0^y \sqrt{9+y^2} \,dx \,dy$$

The first integral was like: $\int y\sqrt{9+y^2} \,dy$. The final integral was like: $u^{3/2}/3$ where $u=9+y^2$.

It will be like this if we plug the limits:
$(9+4^2)/3 - [(9+0^2)/3]$ which will equal to $16/3$. But my teacher said it is $98/3$. How did it even turn out like that?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Noted. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: To get the integral sign you use \int, to get subscripts you use an underscore, and for superscripts a carat.  So \int_0^1 gives $\int_0^1$.  If the sub or superscripts are more than one character enclose them in braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first problem, you forgot about the $x$ in the numerator. You should have
$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_1^{e^x} \frac{x}{y} \,dy \,dx = \int_{-1}^1 x\ln y\Bigr\rvert_1^{e^x} \,dx=\int_{-1}^1 x^2 \,dx.$$
For the second problem, you got the indefinite integral right, but you forgot to raise the numerator to $3/2$ when plugging in limits. You should have
$$\frac{(9+4^2)^{3/2}}{3}-\frac{(9+0^2)^{3/2}}{3}.$$

Comment: Ohhh, totally forgot about the x. That is why. Thanks by the way.